# Unable to find element using Selenium python on 'nested' pages

Tags: html, python-3.x, angular, selenium-webdriver

Goal: populate all fields in the 'nested' password protected page using Selenium python. The pages include Angular code. See screenshot 1. The nesting is within Section 1 - General as all the content therein comes from a different source than the rest of the page. Screenshot 2 shows that mouse-over the circular buttons 1, 2, or 3 displays a different URL in the footer than the address of the 'parent' page itself.

I've tried this code to find the Lease Acres and I get NoSuchElementException:

```
elm = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@ng-model='section1.data.generalSection1.leaseInfo.leaseNumberLeaseAcres']")
```

Also, I run this:

```
browser.page_source
```

And it provides the 'parent' page HTML.

NB in Chrome, doing Save Page As... saves the 'parent' and associated .html files as well; one of those does have the HTML for the Lease Acres etc. (frame).

[Parent Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHebH.jpg)

[Mouse-over the 1,2, or 3 links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbiPe.jpg)

Here is the HTML of the 'parent' page (again, none of the HTML for the 'child' section (Lease Acres etc.) is herein):

```html
<!-- saved from url=(0216)https://afmss.blm.gov/bizflow/portal/wih/basicwih.jsp?sid=0000001001&pid=49479&archive=n&wid=101&ro=n&openpage=page&bizcovecall=y&currow=0&bizcoveid=&wihMode=BASIC_NONE&wihnoactions=&caller=&cu=&tmpTime=1589467253908 -->
<html lang="en" class="x-border-box x-quirks"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://afmss.blm.gov/bizflow/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
 
 <title>Activity - Submit APD in APD Process</title>
 <link href="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/commoncss.mres.1512659262000.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <style type="text/css">
  html, body {
   width: 100%;
  
   height: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
  
  }
  li {clear:both !important}
 </style>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <link href="/bizflow/themes/oceanblue/ielte8.css.1512659261000.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 <![endif]-->
 <link href="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/discussion.css.1512659261000.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/ext-all.css">
 <link href="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/wih.css.1512659262000.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/font-awesome.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/ext-all.js.1512659306000.js.download"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/bfcommon-jsutil-stringutil-urlutil-modalwin-modalpopupclient-positionutil-customcommon-date.1512659289000.js.download"></script><script language="javascript">
var __bfcommonLoaded = true;
var __enableWebBrowserContextMenu = true;
</script>
<style type="text/css">
div.popupbody{}
</style>
<script language="javascript">var __modalWindowMode = true;var __modalWIHMode = true;var __modalMonitorMode = true;</script><style type="text/css">
#WINDOW_TITLE { display:none;}
</style>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/bizflow.calendar.en.js.1589436531000.js.download"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/bizflow.stringtable.en.js.1589436531000.js.download"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/bizflow.wih.en.js.1589436531000.js.download"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/hwmodal-webutil-jquery-1.7.2.min-jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom-jquery.blockUI-jquery.form-mustache.min-discussion-layoutstore-base64-basicwih-userinfo..download"></script>
 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/cookie.js.1512659284000.js.download"></script>

 <script language="javascript">
  <!--
  function setApplicationAdditionalTitle(appid, name)
  {
   $("#appTitle"+appid, WIH_application.document).html("&nbsp;" + name);
  }
  var currentAction = null;
  function navigateUrlApp(action)
  {
   WIH_application.navigateUrlApp(action);
   if ("undefined" != typeof(action)) {
    currentAction = action;
   }
  }
  function closeOEInitiateForm()
  {
   if(currentAction == "NewTaskFromMail")
   {
    navigateUrlApp("ViewMail");
   }
  }
  function reloadApplication()
  {
   WIH_application.navigateUrlApp();
  }

  contextPath = "/bizflow";
  processId = 49479;
  workId = 101;
  useAccessibility = false;
  layoutStore = new LayoutStore({contextPath:contextPath});
  try{
   wihLayoutState = {supplementalTool: {isClosed:true}, instruction: {isClosed:true}, processMap: {isClosed:true}};
   if(typeof(wihLayoutState) != 'object')
   {
    wihLayoutState = {supplementalTool: {isClosed:true}, instruction: {isClosed:true}, processMap: {isClosed:true}};
   }

   if(useAccessibility)
   {
    supplementalToolLayoutState().isClosed = false;
    instructionLayoutState().isClosed = false;
   }

   displayStatus.instruction = !instructionLayoutState().isClosed;
   displayStatus.supplementalTools = !supplementalToolLayoutState().isClosed;
  }
  catch(e)
  {}
  var enableOpenMultipleWIH = false;
  var isArchivedProcess = false;
  var activityInfo = 0;
  var activityAuthority = 768;
  var displayCloseMessage = false;
  var openPageName = "page";
  var bContinue;
  var basicWihReadOnly = "n";
  var imageBasePath = "/bizflow/themes/oceanblue";
  var isNoneUI = true;
  


  setContextRoot(contextPath);
  setCookie('WIHSTYLE', "Basic", "MAX", '/');

  function init()
  {
   bizcoveId = '';
   Ext.require(['Ext.util.*']);
   _readOnly = false;
   _msgtype = "null";
   setWIHOption("completionWindow", false);
   setCurrentUserId("0000006305");
   setWindowTitle("Activity - Submit APD in APD Process");
   setLocalCacheKey("49479-13-101");
   saveOpenTimestamp();
   _readCommentRequired = false;
   
   window.setTimeout(function(){sessionKeepAlive()}, SESSION_KEEP_ALIVE_TIME);
   
   if(typeof(makeMenu) != 'undefined')
   {
    makeMenu();
   }
   

   wihDiscussion = new Discussion("table_commentList", "0000001001",
     49479,
     13,
     101,
     false,
     "0000006305",
     contextPath, imageBasePath,
     {ME:"Me",
      DISCUSSION_PREP_ON: bfMESSAGES.wih.DISCUSSION_PREP_ON,
      TIP_MODIFY_COMMENT: bfMESSAGES.wih.TIP_MODIFY_COMMENT,
      TIP_DELETE_COMMENT: bfMESSAGES.wih.TIP_DELETE_COMMENT,
      MSG_PLEASE_WAIT: bfMESSAGES.wih.MSG_PLEASE_WAIT,
      MSG_DISCUSSION_ENTER: bfMESSAGES.wih.MSG_DISCUSSION_ENTER,
      MSG_WIH_CANNOT_MODIFY_DISCUSSION: bfMESSAGES.stringtable.MSG_WIH_CANNOT_MODIFY_DISCUSSION,
      MSG_WIH_CANNOT_DELETE_DISCUSSION: bfMESSAGES.stringtable.MSG_WIH_CANNOT_DELETE_DISCUSSION,
      MSG_ADDED_NEW_COMMENT: bfMESSAGES.wih.MSG_ADDED_NEW_COMMENT,
      MSG_THERE_ARE_NEW_COMMENTS: bfMESSAGES.wih.MSG_THERE_ARE_NEW_COMMENTS,
      FROM_PROCESS: bfMESSAGES.wih.FROM_PROCESS,
      COMMENT_TYPE_REPLY: bfMESSAGES.wih.COMMENT_TYPE_REPLY,
      COMMENT_TYPE_FORWARD: bfMESSAGES.wih.COMMENT_TYPE_FORWARD,
      COMMENT_TYPE_COMPLETE: bfMESSAGES.wih.COMMENT_TYPE_COMPLETE},
     {modify:true});

   window.setTimeout(function(){
    wihDiscussion.load();
    
   }, 1);

   

   window.setTimeout(function(){
    $('#WIH_action').attr("src", contextPath + "/bizcoves/wih/action.jsp?basicWihReadOnly=" + basicWihReadOnly + "&currow=0&bizcoveid=&caller=&wihnoactions=&showActionButton=n&archive=n&processId="+processId + "&workId=" + workId);
    $('#WIH_application').attr("src", contextPath + "/bizcoves/wih/applist.jsp?basicWihReadOnly=" + basicWihReadOnly + "&noAppBtn=true&processId="+processId + "&workId=" + workId);
   }, 1);
  }
  function checkReadComment()
  {
   
   return false;
   
  }

  var openPageName = "page";
  

  function ShowWindow(newURL, newName, strTitle, width, height, scroll)
  {
   var obj = top;
   var l = screen.width/2 - width/2;
   var t = screen.height/2 - height/2;
   var win = window.open(newURL, newName, "left="+l+",top="+t+",width="+width+",height="+height + ",scrollbars=" + scroll );
   return win;
  }

  function ShowWindowWithObject(newURL, newName, strTitle, width, height, scroll, objectName)
  {
   return ShowWindow(newURL, newName, strTitle, width, height, scroll);
  }
  
  //-->
 </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 
 try{
//  $(window).unload(window_onbeforeunload);
  $(window).bind("beforeunload", window_onbeforeunload);
//  window.attachEvent("onbeforeunload", window_onbeforeunload);
//  window.attachEvent("onunload", window_onbeforeunload);
 } catch(e){};
 $(window).resize(function(){if(isModalWindowMode()){modalWindowOnResize()}});

 function getAttachmentAccordionTitle()
 {
  var accordionTitle = "<div style='float:left;' >"+ bfMESSAGES.wih.ATTACHMENT + "&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
  
  return accordionTitle;
 }
 function getInternalDiscussionAccordionTitle() {
  var accordionTitle = "<div style='float:left;' >"+bfMESSAGES.wih.DISCUSSION+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";

  
  accordionTitle += '<div style="float:right"><button title="' + bfMESSAGES.wih.ADD_NEW_DISCUSSION + '" class="accordionNewColorButton" id="btnAddDiscussion" onclick="return addNewDiscussion(event)" >' + bfMESSAGES.wih.ADD_NEW_DISCUSSION + '</button>' +
    '<button title="Refresh" class="accordionRefreshButton" id="btnRefreshDiscussion" onclick="reloadDiscussion({event:event});"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></div>';
  
  return accordionTitle;
 }
 function addNewDiscussion(event) {
  var ret = openDiscussionPopup({"processId": "", "mode": "New", "commID": ""}, processId, workId);
  try {event.stopPropagation();} catch(e){};
  return false;
 }

 function addTab() {
  WIH_application.addTab("New Correspondence", "http://www.bizflow.com");
  return false;
 }

 function openNewCorrespondence(event) {
  openPopup(contextPath + "/correspondence/newCorrespondence_step1.jsp?&processId="+processId + "&workId=" + workId, bfMESSAGES.wih.NEW_CORRESPONDENCE, "newCorrespondence", 1000, 800);
  try {event.stopPropagation();} catch(e){};
  return false;
 }

 function getCorrespondenceAccordionTitle() {
  var attachmentTitle = "<div style='float:left;' >"+bfMESSAGES.wih.CORRESPONDENCE+"&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>";
  attachmentTitle += "<div style='float:left;display:none' class='countButton' id='lengthOfCorrespondence'>0</div>";
  
  attachmentTitle += '<div style="float:right"><button title="' + bfMESSAGES.wih.ADD_NEW_CORRESPONDENCE + '" class="accordionNewColorButton" id="btnAddCorrespondence" onclick="return openNewCorrespondence(event);" >' + bfMESSAGES.wih.ADD_NEW_CORRESPONDENCE + '</button>' +
    '<button title="Refresh" class="accordionRefreshButton" id="btnRefreshCorrespondence" onclick="reloadCorrespondence({event:event});"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button></div>';
  
  return attachmentTitle;
 }
 function setCorrespondenceLength(length) {
  $("#lengthOfCorrespondence").html(length);
  if(0 == length) {
   $("#lengthOfCorrespondence").hide();
  } else {
   $("#lengthOfCorrespondence").show();
  }
 }
</script></head>















 
 










<body style="margin:0; border:0;background-color:lightgray;" class="x-body x-webkit x-chrome x-reset" id="ext-gen1018">
<div id="notify"></div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  init();
  
 });
</script>
<div class="wih-toolbar-buttons" style="overflow:hidden;display:none;height:0px;" id="menubar">
 <div id="menuToolbar" style="width:100%"></div>
 <iframe id="WIH_action" name="WIH_action" title="Action frame" style="display:none" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/action.html" width="1px" height="1px"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="divApplicationTab" style="display: none; height: 18px;">
 
 <iframe id="WIH_application" name="WIH_application" title="Application frame" style="display: none; height: 18px;" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/applist.html" width="100%" height="25px" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" noresize="" scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
<iframe id="WIH_information" name="WIH_information" title="Information frame" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/saved_resource.html" width="100%" height="100%" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" border="0" frameborder="0" framespacing="0"></iframe>


<div id="appListBox2" class="appListBoxOuter" style="display: none;"></div>
<form id="ajaxForm"></form>
<div class="wih-supplemental-tools wih-supplemental-tools-panel" id="wihSupplementalTools" style="display:none">
 <div class="accordion_menu" style="overflow: hidden;height:100%" id="wihAttachments">
  
  <button style="margin-top: 10px;margin-left: 10px" class="colorButton" title="Add new" onclick="openAddAttachmentWin()">Add new</button>
  
  <div class="content-west accordion_menu" style="height:100%">
   <div class="wih-attachments" id="WIH_attachment">
    <div class="loaderIcon">
     <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw margin-bottom"></i>
    </div>
    









<span class="not-enabled-attachment">Attachments are not supported for this activity.</span>

...
LINES CUT TO REDUCE LENGTH
...

<link href="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/dhtmlwindow.css.1512659262000.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/dhtmlwindow.js.1512659288000.js.download" bridgetranslation="no"></script><div id="dhtmlwindowholder"><span style="display:none">.</span></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/bfcommon-jsutil-stringutil-urlutil-modalwin-modalpopupclient-positionutil-customcommon-date.1512659289000.js.download"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" bridgetranslation="no" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/modalpopup-modalpopupapi-urlutil.1512659289000.js.download"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" bridgetranslation="no">
    

    // set bridgetranslation to no for Bizflow Bridge not to change URL.
    // bug18547: All dialog in Outlook open with HTTP 500 error
    // in case of plumtree, plumtree does not handle a code to load a url in a js so make a exposed function on jsp and call it
    function loadFrameURL(obj, url)
    {
        var loaded = false;
        var __bizcoveId = getUrlValue(url, "__bizcoveId");
        if(null != __bizcoveId && __bizcoveId.length > 0)
        {
            var func = eval("typeof(loadFrameURL" + __bizcoveId + ")");
            if("undefined" != func)
            {
                func = eval("loadFrameURL" + __bizcoveId);
                func(obj, url);
                loaded = true;
            }
        }

        if(loaded == false)
        {
            obj.src = url;
        }
    }
</script>


<style type="text/css">
    a span.separator {
        border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
        width: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="modalPopupMax0Overlay" style="padding:0;position:absolute;background-color:#000000;filter:alpha(opacity=50);-moz-opacity:0.5;opacity:0.5;left:0px;top:0px;display:none;width:100%;height:100%">
</div>

<div id="modalPopupMax0" class="ui-corner-all" style="border: 1px solid #aaa;box-shadow: #606060 10px 10px 20px;overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; display: none;" onselectstart="return false">
    <table class="ui-corner-all" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><!-- title bar -->
                <div class="ui-corner-top" id="modalPopupMax0TitleBarBox" style="height:33px;width:100%;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#f0f0f0;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
                    <table class="popup ui-corner-top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:transparent">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td nowrap="">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td _width="99%" valign="middle" nowrap="">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td><span id="modalPopupMax0Title" class="title" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"></span></td>
                                                    <td><div id="modalPopupMax0SubTitle" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"></div></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" id="modalPopupMaxCell0">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tbody><tr><td class="modal-toolbar-holder"><div id="toolbarHolder0"></div></td><td>
            <a href="javascript:_close();" id="modalPopupMax0CloseButton" accesskey="C" title="Close">
             <span class="closeBtnIcon"></span>
            </a>
                                            </td></tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><!-- popup content -->
                <div id="modalPopupMax0Content" class="ui-corner-bottom" style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:0;overflow:hidden;width:100% !important;height:100%">
                    <iframe id="modalPopupMax0Frame" class="bizCoveModalContentArea" title="modalPopupMax0Frame" name="modalPopupMax0Frame" align="middle" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/saved_resource(1).html">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    a span.separator {
        border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
        width: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="modalPopupMax1Overlay" style="padding:0;position:absolute;background-color:#000000;filter:alpha(opacity=40);-moz-opacity:0.4;opacity:0.4;left:0px;top:0px;display:none;width:100%;height:100%">
</div>

<div id="modalPopupMax1" class="ui-corner-all" style="border: 1px solid #aaa;box-shadow: #606060 10px 10px 20px;overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; display: none;" onselectstart="return false">
    <table class="ui-corner-all" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><!-- title bar -->
                <div class="ui-corner-top" id="modalPopupMax1TitleBarBox" style="height:33px;width:100%;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#f0f0f0;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
                    <table class="popup ui-corner-top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:transparent">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td nowrap="">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td _width="99%" valign="middle" nowrap="">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td><span id="modalPopupMax1Title" class="title" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"></span></td>
                                                    <td><div id="modalPopupMax1SubTitle" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"></div></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" id="modalPopupMaxCell1">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tbody><tr><td class="modal-toolbar-holder"><div id="toolbarHolder1"></div></td><td>
            <a href="javascript:_close();" id="modalPopupMax1CloseButton" accesskey="C" title="Close">
             <span class="closeBtnIcon"></span>
            </a>
                                            </td></tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><!-- popup content -->
                <div id="modalPopupMax1Content" class="ui-corner-bottom" style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:0;overflow:hidden;width:100% !important;height:100%">
                    <iframe id="modalPopupMax1Frame" class="bizCoveModalContentArea" title="modalPopupMax1Frame" name="modalPopupMax1Frame" align="middle" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/saved_resource(2).html">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
    a span.separator {
        border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
        width: 0;
    }
</style>

...
2 3 4 and 5 OMITTED
...

<style type="text/css">
    a span.separator {
        border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
        border-left: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
        margin: 0 2px 0 2px;
        width: 0;
    }
</style>

<div id="modalPopupMax6Overlay" style="padding:0;position:absolute;background-color:#000000;filter:alpha(opacity=10);-moz-opacity:0.1;opacity:0.1;left:0px;top:0px;display:none;width:100%;height:100%">
</div>

<div id="modalPopupMax6" class="ui-corner-all" style="border: 1px solid #aaa;box-shadow: #606060 10px 10px 20px;overflow: hidden; padding: 0; position: absolute; display: none;" onselectstart="return false">
    <table class="ui-corner-all" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td><!-- title bar -->
                <div class="ui-corner-top" id="modalPopupMax6TitleBarBox" style="height:33px;width:100%;margin:0;border:0;padding:0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#f0f0f0;border-bottom: 1px solid #FFFFFF;">
                    <table class="popup ui-corner-top" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" style="background-color:transparent">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td nowrap="">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tbody><tr>
                                        <td _width="99%" valign="middle" nowrap="">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td><span id="modalPopupMax6Title" class="title" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"></span></td>
                                                    <td><div id="modalPopupMax6SubTitle" style="overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;"></div></td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                        <td style="vertical-align: middle" align="right" id="modalPopupMaxCell6">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                            <tbody><tr><td class="modal-toolbar-holder"><div id="toolbarHolder6"></div></td><td>
            <a href="javascript:_close();" id="modalPopupMax6CloseButton" accesskey="C" title="Close">
             <span class="closeBtnIcon"></span>
            </a>
                                            </td></tr>
                                            </tbody></table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                            
                        </tr>
                    </tbody></table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><!-- popup content -->
                <div id="modalPopupMax6Content" class="ui-corner-bottom" style="background-color:#ffffff;padding:0;overflow:hidden;width:100% !important;height:100%">
                    <iframe id="modalPopupMax6Frame" class="bizCoveModalContentArea" title="modalPopupMax6Frame" name="modalPopupMax6Frame" align="middle" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" src="./Activity - Submit APD in APD Process_files/saved_resource(7).html">
                    </iframe>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>


<!--
Do not delete this dummy form. this form is to get  the url of blank html page for portal bridge
//-->
<form action="https://afmss.blm.gov/bizflow/includes/modalpopup/blank.jsp" name="blankform">
    
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var __basePath = "/bizflow";
    var __currentModalIndex = -1;
    var maxModalCount = 7;
    var maxModalIndex = maxModalCount - 1;
    var _browser = "NS";
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
 useLayoutFramework = false;
 function getWIHActionFrame() {
  return this.frames["WIH_action"];
 }
</script>
<input type="hidden" name="_orgContextInfoData" id="_orgContextInfoData" value="...">








</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a matter of switching to the right frame. From [FAQs](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions)

Q: How do I type into a contentEditable iframe?
A: Assuming that the iframe is named "foo":

```
driver.switchTo().frame("foo");
WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
editable.sendKeys("Your text here");
```